# How to remove metadata fields from not including in query in typeorm nestjs

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

`const influencers = await queryRunner.manager.createQueryBuilder().from(InfluencerAccount, 'influencer').select(['influencer.id', 'influencer.email']).where({providerId: IsNull()}).getMany()`

above is code which runs inside some migration. Now i had made a migration before that for deletedAt

await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "influencer_accounts" ADD "deleted_at" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT null`)

It gives me this error when i drop the schema and run again

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fpu3.png)

error description :- query: SELECT "influencer"."id" AS "influencer_id", "influencer"."email" AS "influencer_email" FROM "influencer_accounts" "influencer" WHERE ( "influencer"."provider_id" IS NULL ) AND ( "influencer"."deleted_at" IS NULL )
query failed: SELECT "influencer"."id" AS "influencer_id", "influencer"."email" AS "influencer_email" FROM "influencer_accounts" "influencer" WHERE ( "influencer"."provider_id" IS NULL ) AND ( "influencer"."deleted_at" IS NULL )
error: error: column influencer.deleted_at does not exist

What should i do ?

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not an image.

Comment: Hey there, its an error will update the description